# CSS for designing text and amount same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, styles, bootstrap-modal

I have a requirement to design something like below. I'm using bootstrap in MVC 5. This is for a responsive UI. I need to show like below in a bootstrap modal popup.

---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id mi neque. Donec pulvinar quam diam, at accumsan odio pretium ac................................................................................................... $xx,xxx.xx

Balance..................................................................................................................................... $xx,xxx.xx

Last Payment mm-dd-yyyy ........................................................................................................  $x,xxx.xx

---

Comment: Have you considered using a table?

Comment: Yes. Currently I'm using table to do this. But not sure how to do the first row, where I need content and amount same line.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/jmjdsuLx/1/

Comment: can you put a photo of paper design or photo of same sample design you saw somewhere else?

Comment: @ShalinPatel This is the requirement I had. I don't have any sample design for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow for the text to hang above the value you need to use divs and float the value to the right. Keep in mind that depending on the length of the description it may be possible that the cost will still get bumped down a line.

```html
<div style="width: 600px">
  <div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id mi neque. Donec pulvinar quam diam, at accumsan odio pretium ac<span style="float: right;">$xx,xxx.xx</span>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: whitesmoke;">
  Balance<span style="float: right;">$xx,xxx.xx</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  Last Payment mm-dd-yyyy<span style="float: right;">$x,xxx.xx</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. This works perfectly. Thank you !!

Comment: Only one concern I have is I can't add dotted lines between the content and cost. That's fine. Happy with the current changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your problem. hope it might be helpful to you

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id mi neque. Donec pulvinar quam diam, at accumsan odio pretium </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
<table class="table table-hover">

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>ac........</td>
    <td>$xx,xxx.xx</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Balance....</td>
    <td>$xx,xxx.xx</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>$xx,xxx.xx</td>
    
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need the content and amount in same line.

Answer (score 0):

This should handle aligning the amount with the text.

```css
tr td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

table {
  background-color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id mi neque. Donec pulvinar quam diam, at accumsan odio pretium ac</td>
    <td>$xx,xxx.xx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Balance</td>
    <td>$xx,xxx.xx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Payment mm-dd-yyyy</td>
    <td>$x,xxx.xx</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to have content full width so that it will show above the amount text. If the description is very long then there won't be any space.

Comment: Not in a table but it is possible.

Comment: I have added another answer to solve the problem with divs.